# iOS screen capture - Why is drawViewHierarchyInRect output blurry when zoomed in?

Tags: ios, screenshot

I'm attempting to capture a UIWebView programmatically. I tried 2 different techniques.

**renderInContext**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0)
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

**drawViewHierarchyInRect**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0)
view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Below is the image output of the two techniques after saving to png. The capture source was a pdf file rendered in UIWebView on my iPhone 6, zoomed in. When I don't zoom in, the output for both look the same.

I'd like to use drawViewHierarchyInRect if possible because it's running much faster, and my app will ideally capture the screen 10 times per second. renderInContext is taking about 100ms and drawViewHierarchyInRect is taking about 25ms.

**UPDATE**

renderInContext takes 100ms when not zoomed. It's taking 4s when fully zoomed! drawViewHierarchyInRect is constant.

[image: renderInContext output]
[image: drawViewHierarchyInRect output]

Comment: What was the value for `scale` in your `drawViewHierarchyInRect` example?

Comment: It was: let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale. Just re-ran the code with 0, and got same results, so I updated the question.

Comment: When `drawViewHierarchyInRect` was introduced at WWDC 2013's [Implementing Engaging UI in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/226/), it was presented as a faster alternative to `renderInContext`. On the basis of what you describe, it looks like it must be achieving this performance gain by just returning a transformed rendition of some pre-existing snapshot rather than re-rendering the view.